# Cant find folder in MAC Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, cocoapods

I need to install cocoa pods. So, to create Pods file I need to access to the folder where the app is. But ls can't find it, as proven in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h373E.jpg) screenshot.

I am not very experienced in Unix, searching in the net I did ls -a to see if it is hidden, but no result.

Anybody could help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cd` command doesn't allow spaces. You `cd`-ed to your "iOS" folder, not your "iOS Apps" folder, as seen in the Terminal prompt in your screenshot (`Admins-iMac:iOS admin$` instead of `Admins-iMac:iOS Apps admin$`). Use a backslash (`\`) to escape the space:

```
cd iOS\ Apps
```

You will see your folder

**EDIT** (in response to @l00phole's comment)

You can also use quotation marks to delimit paths with spaces

```
cd "iOS Apps"
```

Comment: It works. I need to wait to upvote your answer. Thank you man.

Comment: Or you can use single- or double-quotes.

Comment: More accurately, you can use double quotes if you DO want variables expanded, e.g. `cd "$HOME/somewhere"` and single quotes if you don't want/need them expanded.